# Jenkins building on a remote machine

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

I can only build my system on a FreeBSD 5 machine.
I am looking and introducing gerrit and Jenkins into my team.
I have setup the server running gerrit and Jenkins both on a Debian machine for now.
What is the standard way of dealing with Jenkins building on a remote server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way would be to install a Jenkins Slave on the remote server.  See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds

You then setup the job that must be built on a FreeBSD 5 machine, to only only run on that slave/node.  This is can be achieved within the job configuration by specifying the FreeBSD machine by name.

If you don't want other Jenkin jobs to run on that FreeBSD machine, you can configure the slave to only run jobs that are tied to it.  See step 4 in the [JENKINS Step by step guide to setup master and slave machines](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines) for the config page that you need to do this.